# Get specific String from String Array by int

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

I got an String Array like this:

```
 public static String[] SOM = new String[] { 
    "", "","", "","something", "something","something", "something","", ""};
```

Lets say I want to check the what the String at position number 4 is. How can I get only that single String?

Comment: SOM[3]. that's all you need.  Remember that array indices are zero based so the first element is zero, the second is one and so on.

Comment: Simple and effective! Thanks a lot! @Simon

Comment: You're welcome.  Frank took the time to compose a working example.  You should accept his answer.

Comment: Have to wait 8 minutes for some reason :( @Simon

Comment: Why are you guys downvoting my question? Can somebody please tell me why?

Comment: Because people think "this is something you should just know" or "stupid question".  Actually, SO is for professional AND enthusiast programmers and amongst other things, is seen by the community as a learning environment so in my view, your question is perfectly valid.  +1 to wipe out the down votes.

Comment: It's not that it's a stupid question. A simple Google search would have gotten you this. Having people simply give you the solution to basic things doesn't help you either.

Comment: @mango I googled it, but I googeled it wrong. I was convinced that the answear had something to do with index. I have not used a lot of arrays in the past. Try googling something like String array get position and it is not the first thing to apear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do:

```
System.out.println(SOM[3]);
```

Comment: sorry, my fast gun, was not thinking

Comment: You got there in time to convert my -1 into a +1 :)

Comment: More coffee Frank, more coffee.  Or perhaps it should be less coffee?  if (fingerSpeed > brainSpeed){coffee--}else{coffee++}

Comment: just out of bed....+1 for the coffee math, i have to remember that one